# google chart double axis, set format

Tags: javascript, format, google-visualization, axis

I have created a Google bar chart, with two x-axis. 
My problem is that I cannot seem to get the correct format on the bottom axis, which should be shown in percentage.

I have tried to use the following

```
axes:{{},{format:'#%'}}}
```

And in general inserting `format:'#%'` at places that would make sense, but nothing seems to work.

Is there anyone who has an idea for this?

See the entire code here: https://jsfiddle.net/laursen92/azr4kfn0/1/

```
      google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['bar']
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

  function drawStuff() {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Slave number', 'Voltage', '%'],
      ['Slave 1', 12.15, 0.40],
      ['Slave 2', 12.18, 0.50],
      ['Slave 3', 11.80, 0.60],
      ['Slave 4', 13.12, 0.70],
    ]);
    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
      pattern: '##0.00'
    });
    var formatter2 = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
      pattern: '##0%'
    });
    formatter.format(data, 1);
    formatter2.format(data, 2);
    var options = {
      width: 800,

      chart: {
        title: 'Status of slaves',
        subtitle: 'Overview of the voltage and SOC of connected slaves. '
      },

      bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
      series: {
        0: {
          axis: 'voltage'
        }, // Bind series 0 to an axis named 'voltage'.
        1: {
          axis: 'percent'
        } // Bind series 1 to an axis named 'soc'.
      },
      axes: {
        x: {
          voltage: {
            side: 'top',
            label: 'Voltage'
          }, // Top x-axis.
          percent: {
            label: 'Percent',
          } // Bottom x-axis.
        }
      },

    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('dual_x_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an update to your fidde: https://jsfiddle.net/Balrog30/azr4kfn0/4/

I used the a little codepen I wrote to reverse-engineer the changes to the material chart options, which are still mostly undocumented. You can find that here: http://codepen.io/nbering/pen/Kddvge

Here's how the option should be formatted:

```
var options = {
  axes: {
    x: {
      yourAxis: {
        format: {
          pattern: "#%"
        }
      }
    }
 };
```

-- Or --

```
options.axes.x.yourAxis.format.pattern = "#%";
```

Comment: Just one more quick question.
How would you either change the location of the gridlines, for change the amount/ticks?

I would like to have the percentage bar in 0 - 25 - 50 - 75 - 100 %. 
I have made it 0 - 100 %, but it goes 0 - 20 - 40 - 60 - 80 - 100 %

Comment: That's an entirely new question, and I don't know off the top of my head. Look around for answers, as I know others have asked. If you can't find it, you can open a new question.